# How not to store specific variable in database when using setValue(Object)?

Tags: java, json, firebase

I'm trying to minimize the amount of data I have in my database.

I have a class called user which looks like the following:

```java
class User {
    
    private Position pos;
    private String uid;}
```

Right now my database looks like:

```
uid{
    pos{ L1=value,
         L2=value
       }
   uid=value
}
```

Very minimized, in fact I'd prefer not even to have the additional uid because the key is the uid which is the unique identifier anyways.

Now, I want to add an additional variable called working into the class.

```java
class User{
    private Position pos;
    private String uid;
    private boolean working;
}
```

Using ref.setValue(User), the database now becomes this:

```
uid{
    pos{ L1=value,
         L2=value
       }
   uid=value,
   working=value
}
```

I do not need to store the working variable in the database, that's just needless information to send. How do I not send this over, but keep it in my User class? The same goes for the additional String uid. I would prefer to remove that from the database as well, but keep it in the class.

Answer (score 6):

Check out the `@Exclude` and `IgnoreExtraProperties`.

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/database/Exclude

```
class User{
 private Position pos;
 private String uid;
 @Exclude
 private boolean working;
}
```

Comment: That was fast. Thank you. I was at a loss at what to search for here, but your post sent me on the right direction. The solution for me was to use @JsonIgnore

Comment: `@JsonIgnore` is in the Firebase 2.x SDK, `@Exclude` is its equivalent when you're using Firebase 3.x SDK.

Comment: it is not working i have marked field as @Exclude and when i setValue(Object); all fields write on firebase db 

any help

Answer (score 1):

If you are using firebase then change the position of @Exclude above getter method of boolean variable **working**

```
public class User {
    private Position pos;
    private String uid;
    private boolean working;

    @Exclude
    public boolean isWorking() {
        return working;
    }

    public void setWorking(boolean working) {
        this.working = working;
    }
}
```